# An efficient compression algorithm for short text strings

Tags: algorithm, compression

I'm searching for an algorithm to compress small text strings: 50-1000 bytes (i.e. URLs). Which algorithm works best for this?

Comment: Where do you want to use these compressed strings?

Comment: Is this going towards `tinyurls` or something to do with storage space?

Comment: No, tinyurls is not the anwser here.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate `basilio`? What do you want to get or, what is this compression targeted towards?

Comment: I'm interested in an algorithm for compressing URLs, best compression ratio is more important then running cost. Not interested in online services like tinyurls or tr.im. I'm looking for an algorithm not a service. Don't think any other info could be useful...

Comment: @Gumbo: "Text compression algorithms for short strings" is enough for finding algos, why are you so interested in knowing what they are for? I'm sure the OP will be able to find the one that does what he wants.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of ["Compression of ASCII strings in C"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097197/compression-of-ascii-strings-in-c)?

Comment: I have a similar problem to the OP - I am storing application state information in the location hash and would like to compress it to shorten it.

Comment: @Vasily, a small hint: Whenever you're asking a question on SO in the form of, "What is *the best* XYZ?", your question is almost bound to receive votes for closing because asking for the best *might* lead to unnecessary product comparisons, or in the worst case, even flame wars. (It usually takes only a very small change to avoid that: If you asked the same question like, "Please suggest a XYZ.", you wouldn't get as many closing votes, even though it's basically the same question!)

Comment: ~50% compression for URLs - see http://blog.alivate.com.au/packed-url/

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Check out [Smaz](https://github.com/antirez/smaz):

> Smaz is a simple compression library suitable for compressing very short
>   strings.

Comment: See http://github.com/antirez/smaz/blob/master/smaz.c -- this is a variant of coding, not compression per se (at least not entirely). He uses a static word and letter dictionary.

Comment: Note: This is antirez's project. He's one of the principal authors of Redis and has a very strong reputation of releasing high quality, production code.

Comment: The smaz algorithm is optimized for English texts, therefore does not work well for random strings. Here are some samples (`string:orig_size:compr_size:space_savings`): `This is the very end of it.:27:13:52%`, `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet:26:19:27%`, `Llanfairpwllgwyngyll:20:17:15%`, `aaaaaaaaaaaaa:13:13:0%`, `2BTWm6WcK9AqTU:14:20:-43%`, `XXX:3:5:-67%`

Comment: Also take a look at a lower compression but a fast algorithm shoco
http://ed-von-schleck.github.io/shoco

Comment: Add my library Unishox to the list https://github.com/siara-cc/unishox.  It performs better than Smaz and Shoco and supports compressing UTF-8 strings.

Answer (score 33):

Huffman has a static cost, the Huffman table, so I disagree it's a good choice.

There are adaptative versions which do away with this, but the compression rate may suffer. 
Actually, the question you should ask is "what algorithm to compress text strings with these characteristics". For instance, if long repetitions are expected, simple Run-Lengh Encoding might be enough. If you can guarantee that only English words, spaces, punctiation and the occasional digits will be present, then Huffman with a pre-defined Huffman table might yield good results.

Generally, algorithms of the Lempel-Ziv family have very good compression and performance, and libraries for them abound. I'd go with that.

With the information that what's being compressed are URLs, then I'd suggest that, before compressing (with whatever algorithm is easily available), you CODIFY them. URLs follow well-defined patterns, and some parts of it are highly predictable. By making use of this knowledge, you can codify the URLs into something smaller to begin with, and ideas behind Huffman encoding can help you here.

For example, translating the URL into a bit stream, you could replace "http" with the bit 1, and anything else with the bit "0" followed by the actual procotol (or use a table to get other common protocols, like https, ftp, file). The "://" can be dropped altogether, as long as you can mark the end of the protocol. Etc. Go read about URL format, and think on how they can be codified to take less space.

Comment: Not if the huffman table is the same for all files, which would make sense if the files are all similar to each other.

Comment: If you have many, similar, small files, you are doing it all wrong. First, concatenate them all (like tar does), and then compress that. You'll get better compression, and the problem ceases to be "50-1000 bytes".

Comment: @Daniel: depends whether you want random access to the compressed data. Compressing it all together prevents that with most compression systems.

Answer (score 24):

I don't have code to hand, but I always liked the approach of building a 2D lookup table of size 256 * 256 chars ([RFC 1978](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1978), *PPP Predictor Compression Protocol*). To compress a string you loop over each char and use the lookup table to get the 'predicted' next char using the current and previous char as indexes into the table. If there is a match you write a single 1 bit, otherwise write a 0, the char and update the lookup table with the current char. This approach basically maintains a dynamic (and crude) lookup table of the most probable next character in the data stream.

You can start with a zeroed lookup table, but obviosuly it works best on very short strings if it is initialised with the most likely character for each character pair, for example, for the English language. So long as the initial lookup table is the same for compression and decompression you don't need to emit it into the compressed data.

This algorithm doesn't give a brilliant compression ratio, but it is incredibly frugal with memory and CPU resources and can also work on a continuous stream of data - the decompressor maintains its own copy of the lookup table as it decompresses, thus the lookup table adjusts to the type of data being compressed.

Comment: But how would predictor behave with normal English sentence? The given example has very strong redundancy, and the gain is minimal.

Comment: A 256*256 lookup table doesn't sound "incredibly frugal with memory" ...!

Comment: @MikeW Well it's 65 kilobytes.

Comment: @redcalx If it had been 65 bytes I might have agreed !

Answer (score 14):

Any algorithm/library that supports a preset dictionary, e.g. [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/manual.html).

This way you can prime the compressor with the same kind of text that is likely to appear in the input.  If the files are similar in some way (e.g. all URLs, all C programs, all StackOverflow posts, all ASCII-art drawings) then certain substrings will appear in most or all of the input files.

Every compression algorithm will save space if the same substring is repeated multiple times  in one input file (e.g. "the" in English text or "int" in C code.)

But in the case of URLs certain strings (e.g. "http://www.", ".com", ".html", ".aspx" will typically appear once in each input file.  So you need to share them between files somehow rather than having one compressed occurrence per file.  Placing them in a preset dictionary will achieve this.

Comment: Tips on using the custom dictionary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011653/

Answer (score 6):

[Huffman coding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) generally works okay for this.

Comment: This is not a link-only answer; without the link, it's still a valid answer.

Comment: ..and still not a good answer. (Not enough relevant information brought in.)

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about actually compressing the text not just shortening then Deflate/gzip (wrapper around gzip), zip work well for smaller files and text.  Other algorithms are highly efficient for larger files like bzip2 etc.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_archivers) has a list of compression times. (look for comparison of efficiency)

```
Name       | Text         | Binaries      | Raw images
-----------+--------------+---------------+-------------
7-zip      | 19% in 18.8s | 27% in  59.6s | 50% in 36.4s
bzip2      | 20% in  4.7s | 37% in  32.8s | 51% in 20.0s
rar (2.01) | 23% in 30.0s | 36% in 275.4s | 58% in 52.7s
advzip     | 24% in 21.1s | 37% in  70.6s | 57& in 41.6s
gzip       | 25% in  4.2s | 39% in  23.1s | 60% in  5.4s
zip        | 25% in  4.3s | 39% in  23.3s | 60% in  5.7s
```

Comment: He wants to compress text and not files.

Comment: You can compress text and binaries with these algorithms.  In fact we use deflate within a cms system that runs in python.

Comment: An example in C# using gzip for strings is here: http://www.csharphelp.com/archives4/archive689.html

Comment: zlib module in python for compressing strings: http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/module-zlib.html

Comment: gzip (and zlib) uses deflate and adds wrapper/framing overhead.. direct deflate/LZ77 (dictionary overhead and efficiency still depends on implementation of such and settings) can reduce the break-even overhead. This is for "short" strings in the dozens to hundreds of characters, of course (still should have a bit to indicate "was this compressed"? to avoid enlarging data). Larger extra overhead doesn't matter.. as text increases. The numbers posted here appear to be for *large* text-files (many seconds to run!), while OP asks for 50-1000 charters - *very small* in comparison.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to take a look at [Standard Compression Scheme for Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Compression_Scheme_for_Unicode).

SQL Server 2008 R2 use it internally and can achieve up to 50% compression.

Comment: SCSU 'compresses' non-English Unicode in UTF-16/MB encodings. If English-based Unicode / plain-old-ASCII, UTF-8 also 'compresses' 50% of UTF-16..