# How to zip a string?

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails

What is the equivalent of this class in python? https://gist.github.com/2594962

In PHP, it allows you to zip a string.

I'm trying to find the equivaelnt in the following languages: Python, Ruby on Rails and ASP.

I'm hoping there are built in functions for these languages. I couldn't find one in PHP.

### Update

When I say Zip, I am referring to the standard algorithm that windows uses. Not in the sense of an archive. I currently use that class to zip a string, base64 encode it and send it as a request to an internal API.

Comment: What do you mean by `zip` here?

Comment: "zip a string"? That doesn't really mean anything to me. Could you try a few examples?

Comment: PHP has a built-in [`ZipArchive`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php) class.

Comment: @Rocket can that be used to Zip a string - or do you have to zip a file then read the contents out of it?

Comment: So, to clarify, you mean compress in a zip archive?

Comment: @Abs: It can be used to make/read zip files.

Comment: @Abs barring anything else, you can always write the string to a file and then zip that file.  It doesn't make much sense to say 'zip a string'

Comment: Python has a [`zipfile`](http://docs.python.org/library/zipfile.html) library.

Comment: @watcher it does if you want to send a large string to an API.

Comment: @Abs: Have a look at [`ZipArchive::addFromString`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfromstring.php)

Comment: @Rocket thanks I wasn't aware of that PHP function. Btw, who ever down voted me feel free to +1 as I have explained what I meant by "zip a string". ;)

Comment: @Abs then you 'compress' the data, in which case you're looking for a string compression algorithm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138345/best-compression-algorithm-for-short-text-strings.

Comment: @watcher you are probably right, but it has to be something that is common in most languages as a built in function as this will be the way users make a request to an API.

Comment: @Abs: Actually you *have never* really explained what you mean by "zip a string". i.e. Whether it means to turn a string into a zip archive or just compress it the same way the data in one is. Likewise, saying "the standard algorithm that windows uses" doesn't convey much information.

Answer (score 25):

To compress a string using the same method used in `.zip` archives, just use the [`zlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html) module directly (which is what Python's [`zipfile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#module-zipfile) module [does](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/zipfile.py)). Here's a simple example:

```
import zlib

teststr = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus
pretium justo eget elit eleifend, et dignissim quam eleifend. Nam vehicula nisl
posuere velit volutpat, vitae scelerisque nisl imperdiet. Phasellus dignissim,
dolor amet."""

cmpstr = zlib.compress(teststr.encode('utf-8'))
uncmpstr = zlib.decompress(cmpstr)

fmt = '{:>8}: (length {}) {!r}'
print(fmt.format('teststr', len(teststr), teststr))
print(fmt.format('cmpstr', len(cmpstr), cmpstr))
print(fmt.format('uncmpstr', len(uncmpstr), uncmpstr))
```

Output:

```
 teststr: (length 237) 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus\npretium justo eget elit eleifend, et dignissim quam eleifend. Nam vehicula nisl\nposuere velit volutpat, vitae scelerisque nisl imperdiet. Phasellus dignissim,\ndolor amet.'
  cmpstr: (length 157) 'x\x9cMO[\x0e\xc30\x08\xfb\xef)8@\xd5\x93L\xd3\xae\x10%^\xcb\x94W\x03\xf4\xfc\xa3\x9d\xb4\xed\x07\tcc\xfb\xd6\x06\nq\x17+\x94Zn\x83\x84\x95B\x81\xce\x14[\x15D\x85\xda\xa0\x90\xb8\xb3D\xae+!\xb3.\xf4\xd8\x82 g\x93\xa9\x0f(\xbb\xfce\xa2\x8d\xb0B/\x8a\x0f\xf0\x135\xcd\xe4H\xe2\xb5\xb2\x08\x17\xda-\x94\xefm\xa1\xbbo\x076\x8e\x96\x039%O\xbd\x89a\xc0\xd1\xf3\xcb\xd1\xb2i\x0f\x1e\xe7`\r \x89\xae\x1d,\xbb\xe1\xa2\x13\x97\x8e\x91\x18\xff\x99~v\xf3\xf4iu6Z\xde\xf8\xa6X\r'
uncmpstr: (length 237) 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus\npretium justo eget elit eleifend, et dignissim quam eleifend. Nam vehicula nisl\nposuere velit volutpat, vitae scelerisque nisl imperdiet. Phasellus dignissim,\ndolor amet.'
```

Answer (score 8):

Python has a `zipfile` module which allows you to read/write zip archives.

The `zipfile.ZipFile` class has a `writestr()` method that can create a "file" in the archive directly from a string.

So no, you don't have to write your string to a file before archiving it.

**Update after question edit**

You say you don't want an archive but the linked PHP code does just that -- creates a PK-Zip archive. In Python you do the same with `zipfile`. Here's an example that creates a zip and adds one file to it -- all in-memory, without physical files.

```
import zipfile
from cStringIO import StringIO

f = StringIO()
z = zipfile.ZipFile(f, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
z.writestr('name', 'some_bytes_to_compress')
z.close()

output_string = f.getvalue()
```

`output_string` will be the compressed content in PK-Zip format.

If you control both sending and receiving side and you don't need to send multiple compressed files in one chunk of data, using PK-Zip is overkill. Instead, you could just use the `zlib` module which implements the compression for PK-Zip.

```
import zlib

output_string = zlib.compress('some_bytes_to_compress')
```

And then you can decompress it (assuming Python):

```
decompressed_string = zlib.decompress(output_string)
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't know it exactly what you need but you might find this interesting. I use here the zipfile module with a string-file-like object

```
import zipfile
import StringIO

s = StringIO.StringIO()  # s is a file like object
z = zipfile.ZipFile(s, 'w')  # this is a zip archive
z.writestr('file1.txt', 'Hello, world') # create a "file" inside the archive called 'file1.txt' and write 'hello world' into it
z.close() # close the archive

print s.getvalue()  # this is the content of the string
s.close()  # close the string file-like object
```

Watch the PK start inside the string

Comment: When you print s, is that the compressed version of the string?

Comment: By default, `ZipFile` doesn't compress. You have to use the `ZIP_DEFLATED` argument. See the docs.

Comment: @Abs: `s` is a `StringIO` object which is a memory-resident file-like object, so while it will contain the compressed string, it also has a number of other things that make up the format of a `.zip` file (such as a header), as well as who-knows-what type of internal stuff that is used to maintain the data in memory.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import zipfile

content = 'foo bar'
filename = 'test.txt'
zipfile_name = 'test.zip'
zipfile_path = os.path.join('/tmp', zipfile_name)
with zipfile.ZipFile(zipfile_path, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as z:
    z.writestr(filename, content)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**